# Check duplicates copy in one cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code to check duplicates, If it find duplicates (or more) in cell L, is it possible to copy the values from cells in the K column into ONE cell?

```
Sub check_duplicates()
    Dim x As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim rng As String


    LastRow = Range("L65536").End(xlUp).Row
    For x = LastRow To 1 Step -1
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("L2:L" & x), Range("L" & x).Value) > 1 Then
            Range("L" & x).Copy
        End If
    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: I do not get what you want to past in the column K. You want to paste all the duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

I hope is what you want to do, let me know.

[image: Before code:]

[image: After]

```
Sub Test()
Dim lastrow As Long


lastrow = Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow

lastrow = Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For j = i + 1 To lastrow

            If Range("L" & j).Value = Range("L" & i).Value Then

                    If Not IsEmpty(Range("K" & i)) Then

                        Range("K" & i) = Range("K" & i) & "," & " " & Range("L" & j)
                        Rows(j).EntireRow.Delete

                     Else

                        Range("K" & i) = Range("L" & j)

                    End If

                j = j - 1

            End If

    Next j

Next i

End Sub
```